# On Click Navigate to different page at particular point

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, jquery-cookie

On clicking link in page 1, it should go to page 2 at a particular point. I've tried using cookies, hashtags.. It is not working. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can do this?

```
jQuery('.acco').click(function() { // Page - 1
    jQuery('body.page-id-2').animate({ // Page - 2
        scrollTop: jQuery('a#example').offset().top
    }, 1000);    
});
```

I've used settimeout. It is working fine. But the issue is once again, if we refresh the page, it is scrolling down. Only on clicking the page-1 link, it should scroll in page-2. Here is the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery('body.page-id-2').animate({            
            scrollTop: jQuery('a#example').offset().top
        }, 1000);    
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Your question isn't making sense can you explain it more?

Comment: If you want people to help you, you need at least to paste snippet of your problematic code.

Comment: @Nurzhan, can u pls check above code?

Comment: can you share html snippet

Comment: This solution might be helpful https://web-design-weekly.com/snippets/scroll-to-position-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

To animate page to a particular position on by looking up a hashra you can use following code.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if(window.location.hash == '#example'){
        jQuery('html,body').animate((
              scrollTop: jQuery('#example').offset().top
         }, 1000);
     }
});
```

Comment: This will make the page scroll even after it is refreshed, the question says that  "But the issue is once again, if we refresh the page, it is scrolling down"

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the issue about page refresh, you need to set a cookie in page 1, and in page 2, check for this cookie, and if you find it, then scroll the page and remove the cookie, otherwise, do nothing

Comment: Thanks.. I've tried it.. $.cookie('demo_cookie', 'Demo Cookie'); Issue is $.cookie is not a function at <anonymous>:1:3.. also tried jQuery.cookie same error in console.. Any idea to solve this..

Comment: just use `document.cookie`

Comment: function WriteCookie() {
document.cookie = "demo_page1=page1";
var webUrl = window.location.href;
if (webUrl.search("/page-2/") >= 0) {
document.cookie = "demo_page2=page2";
}
}